# Pointing a Posterous blog to a subdirectory on a custom domain?

Tags: posterous

It's easy to use Posterous with a custom domain or subdomain.

But if my main website is on www.mydomain.com is it possible to have a Posterous blog on www.mydomain.com/blog, instead of blog.mydomain.com?

Comment: I have the same questions about add blogger to an existing website as an extra page, example: www.mywebsite.com/blog this is the format I amm currently trying to add through godaddy but can only do it as subdomain

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy actually. Once you've logged into Posterous, click on your site in the left hand panel and then click on settings on the right above post by email.

Under settings there is a "custom domain" section. From there all you'll need to do is create a new cname record (if you use cpanel this is pretty easy to do).

Here is posterous link as well: http://help.posterous.com/how-do-i-use-a-custom-subdomain-with-posterou

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you cannot set up a Posterous blog as a subdirectory. You can, however, set up a custom domain such as **blog.example.com**, then point www.example.com/blog to blog.example.com using htaccess, but depending on your situation that may not be ideal.

Here's an .htaccess file set up that will point a subdirectory to a subdomain:

```
# Externally redirect direct client requests for subdomain-subdirectory URLs
# to subdomain URLs without subdomain-subdirectory URL-path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /sd_[^/]+/
RewriteRule ^sd_([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 [R=301,L]
#
# Externally redirect non-canonical domains and subdomains
# (extra or missing "www") to canonical domain and subdomains
RewriteCond www>%{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)>example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.www\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com\.?:[0-9]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
# Internally rewrite all but "main domain" URL-requests to
# subdomain subdirectory filepaths unless previously done
RewriteCond $1 !^sd_
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sd_%1/$1 [L]
```

From: [Redirect Folder to Subdomain - Guru of Search](http://www.guruofsearch.com/redirect-folder-to-subdomain)